# How to set a timeout on Google Gemini generate content request with the Vertex AI SDK for Python

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-gemini

I am using Google's [Vertex AI SDK for Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest) to access the [Gemini Pro](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/model-reference/gemini) model and generate content. I would like to set a timeout (e.g. 30 seconds) for the generate content call to complete or raise an exception.

Setting a timeout is easy if I use an HTTP library like Requests and query the Gemini REST endpoint directly, but how can I implement the same functionality with the Vertex AI SDK for Python?

Here is a example of the code I use to generate content:

```
from vertexai import init
from vertexai.preview.generative_models import GenerativeModel
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'path/to/json/credential/file.json')
init(
    project=credentials.project_id, location='northamerica-northeast1',
    credentials=credentials)
model = GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')
response = model.generate_content("Pick a number")
print("Pick a number:", response.candidates[0].content.text)
```